# Install of IIS role and Windows Update both fail

Tags: iis, windows-update, windows-server-2016

I have a client that uses a database application called DocSTAR.  They recently had to upgrade their server OS because the new version of DocSTAR doesn't support older versions of Windows Server.  We got them new server hardware so that they could have their SQL server separate from their domain controller server, and installed Windows Server 2016 on it.  After getting SQL installed and getting the new server physically installed and put onto their domain, we then contacted the company that distributes and handles DocSTAR, letting them know they could install DocSTAR and transfer the data over to the new server.

This is where the issues came up.  While trying to install and configure DocSTAR, DocSTAR's installation also tried to automatically install IIS.  This failed, and looking up the error in the CBS.log mentions that it is because the files could not be found (I'm sorry, I forgot to document the exact error code, my fault).  Tried manually installing IIS through the Feature & Roles GUI, same error.  Research said that it's possible that it was failing because there were updates installed that required a system reboot to be applied before the role install would work.  Tried restarting the server, didn't fix the issue.  Noticed that there was a update waiting to get downloaded and installed, so figuring the update might fix the issue, we tried installing the update.

Didn't work, error 0x80070003.  Researched this error, and tried doing an sfc /scannow, tried stopping the update service, clearing the temp files and downloads, then starting the service and trying again, didn't work.  Tried the dism /online /restorehealth and that didn't fix the issue either.  Now I'm getting error 0x80070002.

If I remember correctly Windows Update and the Features & Roles installation GUI use the same underlying systems, right?  So if update isn't working, installing a new feature won't work, so I've been concentrating my efforts on fixing the Windows Update, but I can't seem to find the solution.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Getting error 0x800705b4 from Windows Update Service now.  Tried built in troubleshooter per suggested fix for that error.  Still "corruption" in the update database.  Tried deleting downloaded update files to clear corruption.  Tried installing DocSTAR with John again.  Got the IIS install error again.  Took screenshots with both the required features to be installed in a list, but also the errors.  Saved logs as well.  Manually tried to install IIS and got error 0x80073701.

So Error codes from Windows:
0x80070003
0x80070002
0x800705b4
0x80073701

From DocStar/Eclipse:
14081

Comment: Next few comments will be highlights from the system log

Comment: WindowsUpdateClient Event ID 20
update install fail error 0x8024001E

Comment: DistributedCOM Event ID 10016
"The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
{D63B10C5-BB46-4990-A94F-E40B9D520160}
 and APPID 
{9CA88EE3-ACB7-47C8-AFC4-AB702511C276}
 to the user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM SID (S-1-5-18) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool."

Comment: Windows Remote Management Event ID 10149
"The WinRM service is not listening for WS-Management requests. 

 User Action 
 If you did not intentionally stop the service, use the following command to see the WinRM configuration: 

 winrm enumerate winrm/config/listener"

Comment: DistributedCOM Event ID 10016
"The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
{8D8F4F83-3594-4F07-8369-FC3C3CAE4919}
 and APPID 
{F72671A9-012C-4725-9D2F-2A4D32D65169}
 to the user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM SID (S-1-5-18) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool."

Comment: DistributedCOM Event ID 10028
DCOM was unable to communicate with the computer 129.250.35.250/208.67.220.222/4.2.2.3 using any of the configured protocols; requested by PID      234 (C:\Windows\system32\dcdiag.exe).

Comment: Next few comments will be from the application log

Comment: ESENT Event ID 488
"sqlservr (3380) An attempt to create the file "C:\Windows\system32\LogFiles\Sum\Apitmp.log" failed with system error 5 (0x00000005): "Access is denied. ".  The create file operation will fail with error -1032 (0xfffffbf8)."

ESENT Event ID 413
"sqlservr (3380) Unable to create a new logfile because the database cannot write to the log drive. The drive may be read-only, out of disk space, misconfigured, or corrupted. Error -1032."

Comment: MSMFramework Event ID 1
"Failed to get IP Address from DHCP. The Autonet Address : 169.254.95.120 is assigned to local machine. The application might not be fully functional. Check your IP Address, if the address is not an autonet address, restart the service manually. Or if the address is still an autonet address, please contact your System Administrator to fix this problem."

MR_MONITOR Event ID 195
"Controller ID:  0   BBU disabled; changing WB logical drives to WT, Forced WB VDs are not affected."